# Extremely slowly divergent series - Putnam 2008 A.4 generalization

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

**INTRODUCTION**

Starting from Putnam 2008, Exercise A.4, I tried to generalize the result to series that diverge slowlier than the one presented there. Since I am not too familiar with the necessary instruments (e.g. the Lambert function), I wanted to show my partial results and ask you to comment them, find any mistake, or give some insight on the situation.

(I HAVE DONE SOME EDITING on the last two paragraphs, to account for a mistake I discovered)

---

**ORIGINAL SETTING**

The original divergent series is constructed as follows. Let
$$f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
x & (x \leq e)\\
x\log f(x) & (x>e).
\end{cases}
$$
Then the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{f(n)}$$
diverges.

The function is basically a *product of nested logarithms*, where the number of logarithmic factors grows with $x$, in such a way that $f(x)$ is continuous and monotonically increasing. Thus divergence is proved via divergence of the integral
$$\int_e^{\infty} \frac1{f(x)}dx.$$

---

**GENERALIZATION (CLAIM)**

Let $\alpha$ be a real number such that
$$1< \alpha\leq \frac{e}{e-1}\tag{1}\label{1}$$
and
$$\beta = e^{-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}\cdot W\left(-\frac{\alpha-1}\alpha\right)},\tag{2}\label{2}$$
where $W(x)$ is the principal branch of the Lambert function. Let also $E_1 = e^\beta$ and $$E_k = e^{E_{k-1}}$$ for $k>1$. Similarly define $L_1(x) = \log x$ and $$L_k(x) =\log L_{k-1}(x)$$ for $k>1$. If $f(x)$ is defined as
$$f_\alpha(x)=\begin{cases}
x\log^\alpha x & \left(e < x \leq e^\beta\right)\\
x\log x\log^\alpha\log x & \left( e^\beta <x \leq e^{e^\beta}\right)\\
x\log x\log\log x \log^\alpha \log\log x & \left(e^{e^\beta} < x \leq e^{e^{e^\beta}}\right)\\
\vdots & \vdots \\
x\cdot \prod_{k=1}^{m}L_k(x) \cdot L_{m+1}^\alpha(x) & (E_m < x \leq E_{m+1})\ \ \ (m\geq 1)\\
\vdots & \vdots.
\end{cases}
$$
Then the series
$$\sum_{n=3}\frac1{f_\alpha(n)}\tag{3}\label{3}$$
diverges.

---

**SOME NOTES**

In order to guarantee monotonicity of the piecewise function $f_\alpha(x)$ we need the constituent functions to behave properly. This gives limitations on $\alpha$ given by \eqref{1} and the relationship between $\alpha$ and the connection points given by \eqref{2}.

First of all we wish the component to intersect at some point, and this happens if, for some $\overline x$,
$$x\prod_{k=1}^m L_k(\overline x) L_{m+1}^\alpha(\overline x) = x\prod_{k=1}^{m+1}L_k(\overline x) L_{m+2}^\alpha(\overline x) $$
that is
$$L_{m+1}^{\alpha-1}(\overline x) = L_{m+2}^{\alpha} (\overline x),$$
Letting $\xi = L_{m+1}(\overline x)$ we obtain the equation
$$ \xi^{\alpha-1} = \log^\alpha\xi.$$
This equation has only one solution when $\alpha = \frac{e}{e-1}$ (the two red lines in the Figure below, that are tangent in point $B$), and has to solutions
for $0< \alpha <\frac{e}{e-1}$. In the latter case, the smallest one is
$$\beta = e^{-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}\cdot W\left(-\frac{\alpha-1}\alpha\right)},$$
(the larger one being given by the lower branch of the Lambert function) from which we obtain the connection point
$$\overline x = E_{m+1}.$$ In the Figure, the case $\alpha = \frac32$ is depicted ($A$ marks the intersection between the two lines).

[image]

Note that, from the asymptotic beahviour of the logarithmic function, we can also deduce that in a right neighborhood of $\beta$ we have
$$x\prod_{k=1}^m L_k(x) L_{m+1}^\alpha(x) < x\prod_{k=1}^{m+1}L_k(x) L_{m+2}^\alpha(x).$$

Below a plot of the function $$\beta = \beta(\alpha)$$ (equation \eqref{2}) for $0 <\alpha \leq \frac{e}{e-1}$.

[image]

**I haven't studied this function formally** but we surely have
$$\lim_{\alpha \to \frac{e}{e-1}}\beta(\alpha)= e^{-e\cdot W\left(-\frac1{e}\right)}=e^e,\tag{4}\label{4}$$
and it seems we get
$$\lim_{\alpha \to 1} \beta(\alpha) = e \tag{5}\label{5}.$$

In particular \eqref{5} shows that we can think of the series \eqref{3} as a generalization of the one proposed in the Putnam competition (where $\alpha = 1$, $\beta =e$).

It appears that the reasoning (also in what follows) can be extended to the more general
case $0<\alpha\leq \frac{e}{e-1}$. However the divergence when $0<\alpha< 1$ is trivial. When $\alpha > 1$, though, each constituent function would give rise by itself to a convergent series (by Condensation Test), and yet our series diverge.

---

**PROOF OF DIVERGENCE (SKETCH)**

As stated we need to prove that the integral diverges. Now, we have
$$\mathcal I_0 = \int_e^{e^\beta} \frac1{x \log^{\alpha} x}dx = -\frac1{\alpha-1}\left[\frac1{\log^{\alpha-1}x}\right]^{e^\beta}_e=\frac1{\alpha-1}\left(1-\frac1{\beta^{\alpha-1}}\right),$$which, using \eqref{2}, can be expressed as
$$\mathcal I_0 = \frac1{\alpha-1}\left[1-e^{\alpha\cdot W\left(-\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}\right)}\right].$$

For all the other intervals we get
$$\mathcal I_1 = \int_{E_m}^{E_{m+1}} \frac1{x\prod_{k=1}^m L_m(x)\cdot L_{m+1}^{\alpha}(x)}dx =-\frac1{\alpha-1}\left[\frac1{L_{m+1}^{\alpha-1}(x)}\right]_{E_m}^{E_{m+1}}=\frac1{\alpha-1}\left(\frac1{\log^{\alpha-1}\beta}-\frac1{\beta^{\alpha-1}}\right).$$ Using again \eqref{2} yields
$$\mathcal I_1 = \frac1{\alpha-1}\left[\frac1{\left(-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}\cdot W\left(-\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}\right)\right)^{\alpha-1}}-e^{\alpha\cdot W\left(-\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}\right)}\right].$$

A plot of $\mathcal I_0$ (yellow) and $\mathcal I_1$ (green) as functions of $\alpha$ is depicted below.

[image]

Here again **a more formal study of these functions** is required. From what I have done so far, it appears that both are limited functions of $\alpha$.

We conclude that the integral diverges, and so does the series. Also, as $\alpha$ approaches $\frac{e}{e-1}$ the "speed" at which the series diverges rapidly decreases, since the integral increments are less then $1$ in the (larger and larger) intervals $[E_m, E_{m+1}]$.

---

**QUESTIONS**

First of all, I am interested in spotting any error in my approach.

Secondarily, since I have been largely qualitative in some steps of the reasoning, I was wondering if everything can be made more formal, in the last two paragraphs above especially (study of $\beta(\alpha)$, $\mathcal I_0(\alpha)$, and $\mathcal I_1(\alpha)$, for example).

Of course any other insight, comment, suggestion is more than welcome.